# Bulk upload custom objects in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, bulk-load

I am using the bulk upload code described at http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/.

The only difference is that i am uploading a custom object type. The object has been defined in SalesForce. But when i refer to the object (named Employee) i get error "Unable to find object: Employee". Tried with Employee_c as well. Same result.

Any pointers would be appreciated

thank you

Sameer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be two underscores and a "c" (`__c`) after a custom Object name.

Try exporting the data from the custom object using the [Apex Data Loader](https://adpdealerservices--fulldev.cs12.my.salesforce.com/dwnld/DataLoader/ApexDataLoader.exe):

1. Click the Export button
2. Log In with your Username and Password
3. Find your custom object in the Salesforce Object list
4. Click Browse and select a location to save the export
5. Select ID at minimum from the list of Fields
6. Note the Query (SOQL) includes the custom Object Name

If you are able to export data from the custom Object, then try to Insert data.

However, if the custom Object does not appear in the list, make sure you are logging in using the correct Username and Password. Sandbox instances all have ".sandbox-name" appended to the Username (where sandbox-name is the name of your sandbox).

If you are still unable to see the custom Object when trying an export, check the permissions (profile and role) of the User you are logging in as, and make sure that User has access to the object.

-- Edit --

I thought you were using the Data Loader to do your bulk load, sorry about that. You may still want to check the permissions of your User, though.

Comment: Thanks, the underscore was the problem. You are correct that i am not using Apex data loader. You are also correct that i need to check permissions for custom objects (as i am getting a different error now, which i think is related to custom object permissions). Thank you Sameer